# Is there a way to copy the layers list from one project to another?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to copy this layers to another project instead add the layers one by one in the other project :

[image: Layers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ProjectSettings, you can find the TagManager file.

This contains all your tags and layers, I'd guess a copy paste into your new project should be allowed.